# Storyboard.GetTarget in Silverlight for Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a problem with WP7 app. I'm trying to write WP7 app form WPF sample code.

```
    private void storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClockGroup clockGroup = (ClockGroup)sender;

        // Get the first animation in the storyboard, and use it to find the
        // bomb that's being animated.
        DoubleAnimation completedAnimation = (DoubleAnimation)clockGroup.Children[0].Timeline;
        Bomb completedBomb = (Bomb)Storyboard.GetTarget(completedAnimation);
```

it seems that there is no ClockGroup class and Storyboard does not have GetTarget method (which is a bit strange cuz there is SetTarget method). Is there a hack to get he same functionality?

Comment: It might help you, if you describe the functionality you that you want to acheive.

Comment: sorry for a late re but i had a BSOD a sec ago. http://www.speedyshare.com/files/23809905/BombDropper.7z

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know little of WPF but in Silverlight or WP7 the children of a `Storyboard` are of type `TimeLine`. Also a StoryBoard itself would have a `Completed` event to which you would be  binding.  So at least the first chunk of the code would look like:-

```
private void storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)sender;

    DoubleAnimation completedAnimation = (DoubleAnimation)sb.Children[0];
```

Now for the tricky bit.

Its actually quite unusual for `Storyboard.SetTarget` to be used in Silverlight code.  I guess that game code is more likely to generate elements and animations in code and therefore more likely to use `SetTarget`.  If this is what you want to do then you will need to build your own attached property that has both Get and Set, have the changed callback on this property call the `Storyboard.SetTarget`.

Here is the code:-

```
public static class StoryboardServices
{
    public static DependencyObject GetTarget(Timeline timeline)
    {
        if (timeline == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("timeline");

        return timeline.GetValue(TargetProperty) as DependencyObject;
    }

    public static void SetTarget(Timeline timeline, DependencyObject value)
    {
        if (timeline == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("timeline");

        timeline.SetValue(TargetProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                    "Target",
                    typeof(DependencyObject),
                    typeof(Timeline),
                    new PropertyMetadata(null, OnTargetPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnTargetPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard.SetTarget(d as Timeline, e.NewValue as DependencyObject);
    }
}
```

Now the `SetTarget` code would become:-

```
 StoryboardServices.SetTarget(completedAnimation, bomb);
```

Then your completed event can retrieve the target with:-

```
 Bomb completedBomb = (Bomb)StoryboardServices.GetTarget(completedAnimation);
```

Comment: thx a lot but Bomb completedBomb = (Bomb)StoryboardServices.GetTarget(completedAnimation);
is a null

Comment: @lukas:  Then either a) you haven't used `StoryboardServices.SetTarget` to set it  or b) the completedAnimation object you are calling the `GetTarget` on isn't the same as the one passed to `SetTarget`.

Comment: Oh i forgot to set one SetTarget. Sorry.
I think i need to use diffrent pattern cuz this one is seriousy slow. I get FPS drop form 35 to 8 :/

Comment: ehh The game is fine, Emulator not