# How to create smooth animation in code at runtime?

Tags: animation, windows-phone-7

In my page i am creating bombs which should be dropped on specified targets.
My problem is whatever is use (Timer,DoubleAnimation,KeyFrameAnimation) the motion of the falling bombs appear jerky.
Can anyone suggest how to create jerk free animations(in code).
Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, testing animation is a bit problematic. I made a few animations that perform horrible in the eumulator ( even though I meet all the requirements like WDDM 1.1), yet they perform great on the device. Just have to check it on a device.

To made this kind of game I suggest the DispatcherTimer class to simulate game loop (I made my HelloWorld game which use it). You will have a general timer that helps you with all animations.

I think that the best fit is DobuleAnimation. So let's code (inside Timer Tick event handler):

```
        Random random = new Random();
        // Create the bomb.
        Bomb bomb = new Bomb();
        bomb.IsFalling = true;

        //Easing function
        var easefall = new QuadraticEase();
        easefall.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn;

        // make some bombs bigger and goes faster
        var randNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
        if (randNumber < 15)
        {
            bomb.Scale.ScaleX = bomb.Scale.ScaleY = 0.8;
            Canvas.SetZIndex(bomb, 1);
        }

        // Position the bomb.            
        bomb.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)(random.Next(0, (int)(canvasBackground.ActualWidth - 30))));
        bomb.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, -200.0);

        // Attach ManipulationStarted click event (for defusing the bomb).
        bomb.ManipulationStarted += bomb_ManipulationStarted;

        // Create the animation for the falling bomb.
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation fallAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        fallAnimation.To = canvasBackground.ActualHeight;
        fallAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(m_secondsToFall);
        fallAnimation.EasingFunction = easefall;

        StoryBoardHelper.SetTarget(fallAnimation, bomb);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fallAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
        storyboard.Children.Add(fallAnimation);

        // Create the animation for the bomb "wiggle."
        DoubleAnimation wiggleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        wiggleAnimation.To = 40;
        wiggleAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3);
        wiggleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        wiggleAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
        var easewiggle = new CircleEase();

        easewiggle.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut;
        wiggleAnimation.EasingFunction = easewiggle;

        StoryBoardHelper.SetTarget(wiggleAnimation, ((TransformGroup)bomb.RenderTransform).Children[0]);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(wiggleAnimation, new PropertyPath("Angle"));
        storyboard.Children.Add(wiggleAnimation);

        // Add the bomb to the Canvas.
        canvasBackground.Children.Add(bomb);

        // Add the storyboard to the tracking collection.            
        m_storyboards.Add(bomb, storyboard);

        // Configure and start the storyboard.
        storyboard.Duration = fallAnimation.Duration;
        storyboard.Completed += storyboard_Completed;
        storyboard.Begin();
```

Also would be great to have some animation when bomb is catched/exploded. A sample:

```
    // display falling bombs
    private void bomb_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        // Get the bomb.
        Bomb bomb = (Bomb)sender;
        bomb.IsFalling = false;

        // Get the bomb's current position.
        Storyboard storyboard = m_storyboards[bomb];
        double currentTop = Canvas.GetTop(bomb);

        // Stop the bomb from falling.
        storyboard.Stop();

        // Play the sound
        m_beep.Play();

        // Reuse the existing storyboard, but with new animations.
        // Send the bomb on a new trajectory by animating Canvas.Top
        // and Canvas.Left.
        storyboard.Children.Clear();

        DoubleAnimation riseAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        riseAnimation.From = currentTop;
        riseAnimation.To = 0;
        riseAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

        StoryBoardHelper.SetTarget(riseAnimation, bomb);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(riseAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
        storyboard.Children.Add(riseAnimation);

        DoubleAnimation slideAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        double currentLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(bomb);
        // Throw the bomb off the closest side.
        if (currentLeft < canvasBackground.ActualWidth / 2)
        {
            slideAnimation.To = -100;
        }
        else
        {
            slideAnimation.To = canvasBackground.ActualWidth + 100;
        }
        slideAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        StoryBoardHelper.SetTarget(slideAnimation, bomb);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
        storyboard.Children.Add(slideAnimation);

        // Start the new animation.
        storyboard.Duration = slideAnimation.Duration;
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

You can find [helper here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485272/storyboard-gettarget-in-silverlight-for-windows-mobile)

PS: I love Silverlight :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is with the things that you're trying to animate and the relationship between them and their surroundings, rather than how you're setting up the animation. I suggest you take a look at some of the following resources:

- [Windows Phone 7 + Silverlight Performance](http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Home/tabid/67/EntryID/196/Default.aspx)
- [Performance of Windows Phone 7 Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/WP7-Performance.aspx)
- [Performance-related posts](http://www.nachmore.com/category/silverlight/performance/) by Oren Nachman (perf guru!)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a Timer reliably for animation - since the birth of Windows timer's have always dropped to almost the bottom of the priority list when it comes to processing priority - so you simply cannot get guaranteed high-frequency low-jitter timer ticks even when your app is idle.

You can use the CompositionTarget.Rendering event to perform hand-crafted animation - but be careful not to do too much mathematics (or other code) within this event as it can slow down your frame rendering rate.

Finally, you can also use the Storyboard/Animation classes to perform animation. I've done this in quite a few [demo cases now](http://script.iron7.com/#/Script/Detail?scriptId=81baa9940368436c8244ab7810331b65&userLowerCaseName=iron7) and seen good, smooth effects - especially when using the real phone rather than when using the emulator (I'm not 100% convinced how the emulator's own drawing clock is triggered!)

As Derek suggests, it might be worth looking at what you are animating - replace your current animated objects with simple shapes (e.g. rectangles) and see if they animate more smoothly.