# how to add/show a UserControl (e.g. popup) in a WP7 app page?

Tags: windows-phone-7

hi i have created a user control.

now i want to add this control to a page e.g. when the user clicks a button (important is, that i dont want to add it direcly in xaml, i want to add id in the c# code section)

how to so this?

Comment: You can place it in the xaml and change visibility/opacity. I used [this code][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606572/waiting-1-second-until-hiding-an-image/5606726#5606726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button's Click event, you could do something like:

```
MyControl control = new MyControl();
// Set whatever properties you need in your control here
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(control);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
                    {

                        Popup popup = new Popup();
                       WPCpopup po = new WPCpopup(popup);

                        popup.Width =                        System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
                        popup.Child = po;
                       popup.VerticalOffset = 300;
                       popup.IsOpen = true;
               }
```

WPCpopup  is usercontrol